# Verification of Gibbs's correction in Boltzmann's principle

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy

Using the formula for the volume of a hypersphere, one can easily deduce, using Stirling's aproximation, that the density of states for a system with $N$ particles with hamiltonian $H=\sum_{k=1}^n\left(\frac{\mathbf{p_{k}^2}}{2m}+V(\mathbf{r}_k;L)\right)$ is:

\begin{equation}\Phi=S(E, V, N) = k_B N \ln \left[ V \left( \frac{4\pi m E}{3h^2N}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} \right] + \frac{3}{2} N k_B
\end{equation}

Suppose that we consider a situation where two identical gases will mix. Considering that the gases initially occupy volumes $V_1$ and $V_2$ and after mixing they'll occupy a volume $V=V_1+V_2$ and keeping the same temperature and density conditions that we'd have at the start, we'd conclude that the variation of entropy is zero since that's a reversible process.

I've been told that using Gibbs's factor $\frac{1}{N!}$ in Boltzmann's principle (where we consider $S=k_B\ln\Phi$, not $\Omega$) yields the correct entropy variation.

However, I'm not getting a positive entropy variation, or anything substantial whatsoever from putting this factor into the expression for entropy.

Any help will be appreciated.